# Changes made to Word add-in's UI does not show up when ran

Tags: office-js, office-addins, word-addins

I have created a basic Word Web Add-in using Visual Studio 2017.
When I run the project in VS, it launches Word and loads my add-in just fine.
However, if I make any changes to the add-in's user interface (HTML code), my changes do not show up when I launch Word.

I have tried restarting VS, restarting the computer, rebuilding the solution.

How do I make it so that I can immediately see my changes after I introduce them?

Comment: Let's start with which technology you're using? Is this VSTO? Office JS APIs? Something else? And where's the code? Please provide a [mcve] so that people can understand what's involved, here.

Comment: @CindyMeister, I'm using Office JS APIs. The issue is not code-related, but rather why changes to code are not reflected when running VS?

Comment: @CindyMeister providing a minimal reproducible example is difficult since this problem appears randomly (in so far as I'm able to determine).  I realize that that doesn't help you in responding to the report but, there it is.  To the OP, check my comment on that 'answer' below for a less drastic workaround for some of the cases.

Answer (score 0):

I have been experiencing a similar problem when using Visual Studio Community 2017 and 2019. This problem appeared several updates ago.The only workaround I have found is to exit Visual Studio and then restart Visual Studio again and go to my solution. If on occasion that does not work I restart my computer. It appears that the problem is based on the Visual Studio  and/or Internet  Explorer Browser cache(s) not being flushed. I have not yet found the magic steps to force the flush.

I use a button command to log a revised line to my console . If I see the revised line I am OK, if the line displayed is not the revised, the go through the steps above.

Comment: I've seen this problem in several forms lately.  For most cases, I can flush out the caches by going to %LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Wef\ and deleting everything in that folder.  On occasion, that does not fix the problem and restarting Visual Studio is required.  On rare occasions that doesn't work so the big hammer needs to come out.